# Trying to set up a secure login I keep getting an error on line 38

Tags: php

I am trying to make a secure login or registration work. Not easy for me, an amateur!

I have been trying to follow the instructions [here](https://www.9lessons.info/2016/04/php-login-system-with-pdo-connection.html):

On my laptop I am running apache2. The error log tells me:

> [Sat May 16 09:22:25.271736 2020] [php7:error] [pid 974] [client
>   127.0.0.1:40112] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on string in
>   /var/www/html/includes/userClass.php:38\nStack trace:\n#0
>   /var/www/html/index.php(44): userClass->userRegistration('Pedroski55',
>   'George22', 'pedroski@163....', 'Peter Rodgers')\n#1 {main}\n 
>   thrown in /var/www/html/includes/userClass.php on line 38, referer:
>   http://localhost/

This should log me in to the allstudentsdb. I do not get an error message:

```
<?php
// connect to my mysql database allstudentsdb
try
{
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=allstudentsdb', 'myusername', 'mypassword', array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => true,));
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$pdo->exec('SET NAMES "utf8"');
return $pdo;
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
$error = 'Unable to connect to the database server' . $e ;
include 'error.html.php';
exit();
}
?>
```

I can't see what the problem is: Any tips from you experts please??

```
33 /* User Registration */
34 public function userRegistration($username,$password,$email,$name)
35 {
36try{
37 $db = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/studentdbReadfrom.inc.php';
38 $st = $db->prepare("SELECT uid FROM neil_users WHERE username=:username OR email=:email");
39 $st->bindParam("username", $username,PDO::PARAM_STR);
40 $st->bindParam("email", $email,PDO::PARAM_STR);
41 $st->execute();
42 $count=$st->rowCount();
43 if($count<1)
44{
45 $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO neil_users(username,password,email,name) VALUES  (:username,:hash_password,:email,:name)");
46 $stmt->bindParam("username", $username,PDO::PARAM_STR) ;
47 $hash_password= password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT); //Password encryption 
48 $stmt->bindParam("hash_password", $hash_password,PDO::PARAM_STR) ;
49 $stmt->bindParam("email", $email,PDO::PARAM_STR) ;
50 $stmt->bindParam("name", $name,PDO::PARAM_STR) ;
51 $stmt->execute();
52 $uid=$db->lastInsertId(); // Last inserted row id
53$db = null;
54 $_SESSION['uid']=$uid;
55 return true;
56 }
57 else
58{
59 $db = null;
60 return false;
61}
62 
63 }
64 catch(PDOException $e) {
65 echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
66 }
67}
```

Comment: Presuming that your first piece of code is what is in `studentdbReadfrom.inc.php`, this should work: `$db = include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/studentdbReadfrom.inc.php');`

Comment: Your $db variable is not pointing to the database connection as you think. This is just a path(string).

Comment: Thanks a lot! That fixed that problem! $db = include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/studentdbReadfrom.inc.php');